# Limit of double integral at origin

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have a problem set with the following problem:

“Prove that, if $D_1={(x,y) | x^2+y^2 \leq r^2}$, then $\ lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \iint_{D_1}    f(x,y) dA =f(0,0)$.

I am just stuck, as I can imagine it visually, but I have no idea what to do since it’s an arbitrary function. Should I switch to polar? Any help or hints is appreciated.

Comment: For completely arbitrary functions $f$, this would seem to be wrong. It's basically saying that the average of any function over a disk centered at the origin is zero as the disk's radius goes to zero. Just take $f(x,y)$ to be a non-zero constant...

Comment: @JohnBarber I’m very sorry, I realize I made a typo that is now fixed.

Comment: Do you mean $D_1=\{(x,y) | x^2+y^2 \leq r^2\}$?

Comment: If $f(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=1$ then there is a contradiction . If $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ then the result is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ this result is very easy to prove. Note that $\frac 1 {\pi r^{2} } \int\int_D 1 dA=1$. Hence $\frac 1 {\pi r^{2} } \int\int_D f(x,y) dA -f(0,0)=\frac 1 {\pi r^{2} } \int\int_D [f(x,y)-f(0,0)] dA$. If $r$ is small enough then $\frac 1 {\pi r^{2} } |\int\int_D [f(x,y)-f(0,0)] dA | <\epsilon \frac 1 {\pi r^{2} } \int\int_D 1 dA=\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I see. If I can just ask a question, how come you can write $\iint f(x,y) dA-f(0,0)$ as $\iint f(x,y) -f(0,0) dA$ ?

Comment: Just split the integral on the right side into two terms. In the second term you are integrating a constant. Take the constant out of the integral. Do you see what is happening?

Comment: Split which integral? The one including both terms? And also, I am not 100% sure either why you were able to factor the $\frac{1}{\pi r^2}$ out of $f(0,0)$ when is wasn’t there initially. Is this related to that?

Comment: General fact: if $\mu$ is a probability measure then $\int f d\mu -c=\int (f-c)d\mu$ for any constant $c$. In particular if $f $ is a non-negative function such that $\int f(x) \, dx=1$ then $\int f(x) \, dx-c=\int (f(x)-c) \, dx$. Same thing with double integrals. In our case $f(x)=\frac 1 {\pi r^{2}}$.

Comment: Ah ok, I see how that would make everything work out. Does this fact have a name or something so I can research it? Just because it still doesn’t seem super clear to me and I feel like reading a bit would help. Either way though, thank you

Comment: As far as I know, there is no name for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

If $f$ is not continuous, then the statement does not necessarily hold. As Kawi pointed out in comments, a counter example is that $f(x,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y)\ne 0$ but $f(x,y)=1$.

So let’s assume that $f(x,y)\in C(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Write the integral in polar form:

$$ \iint_{D_1} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}A=\int_0^r \mathrm{d}R\int_0^{2\pi}f(R\cos\theta, R\sin\theta)R \mathrm{d}\theta$$

Consider $f(R\cos\theta, R\sin\theta) $ as a funtion depending on $\theta$, and apply the first mean value theorem of numerical integration, the preceding formula became

$$\int_0^r \mathrm{d}R\cdot f(R\cos\theta^*, R\sin\theta^*)\int_0^{2\pi}R\mathrm{d}\theta $$

where $\theta^*\in[0,2\pi]$ is a variable depending on $R$. Apply the mean value theorem again, we have

$$\int_0^r f(R\cos\theta^*, R\sin\theta^*)2\pi R \mathrm{d}R =  f(R^*\cos\theta^*, R^*\sin\theta^*)\int_0^r 2\pi R \mathrm{d}R $$

where $0\le R^*\le r$. Multiply the integral by $\frac 1 {\pi r^2}$, take the limit $r\to 0$, and from the continuity of $f$ we see that the original formula is equal to $f(0,0)$.

---

**EDIT:** Actually, there is a more straightforward proof. Apply the mean value theorem directly to the original integral, and the result follows immediately.